# How to remove the scale/axes on a Axes3D Graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm plotting a 3D graph in jupyter notebook using python.
Now I would like to remove this secondary scale in my plot, (not the x,y,z axes).
I have tried using "axes.axis("off")", however, this only disables the normal x,y,z axes which I would like to keep. I will attach my code and 2 images, one with the 3 axes + the scale I wish to delete, and the other with the axes I would like to keep disabled and the scale remaining. For clarity of the feature, I would like gone, any help would be appreciated.

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action = 'ignore', category = FutureWarning)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

from scipy.stats import norm

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

import math

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

data = pd.read_csv("./kc_house_data.csv")

size = data['sqft_living'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
price = data['price'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
bedrooms = data['bedrooms'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

size_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
price_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
bedroom_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

norm_size = size_scaler.fit_transform(size).reshape(-1)
norm_price = price_scaler.fit_transform(price).reshape(-1)
norm_bedrooms = bedroom_scaler.fit_transform(bedrooms).reshape(-1)

graphWidth = 400
graphHeight = 300

f = plt.figure(figsize = (graphWidth / 100.0, graphHeight / 100.0), dpi = 100)
matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
axes = Axes3D(f)
axes.scatter(norm_size, norm_bedrooms, norm_price)
plt.show()
```

[Here is the image with the axes + the scale i want removed:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMI5J.png)

[Here is the image with only the scale (the element i want to remove)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1seT.png)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N5lTwj3s1tVgy_VuvHcSvf6p259wgDJJ/view?usp=sharing

To clarify, the intended result would have the second image only display the graph, and the first to only have the x,y,z axes.

Comment: Can you also post your csv ? Do you mean you want `grid` to turn off ? If yes then you can definitely turn of `ax.grid(False)`

Comment: yes its linked on Gdrive, hope it helps

Comment: No it is not the grid i want disabled but the two labelled scales as illustrated in the second image linked, by setting grid to False these still persist

Comment: From your code, i don't get the secondary axis you showed in the second image attach, Is that your `y axis` ?

Comment: That is odd that you dont get the secondary axis, i am starting to suspect that it may have something to do with jupyter then...

Comment: I don't think something is wrong with the `jupyter` because i also used `jupyter` to plot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off your `grid` and rotate if you want. You also have some imports that you're not using, I removed them just for now.

```py
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action = 'ignore', category = FutureWarning)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from scipy.stats import norm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import math

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

data = pd.read_csv("kc_house_data.csv")

size = data['sqft_living'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
price = data['price'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
bedrooms = data['bedrooms'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

size_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
price_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
bedroom_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

norm_size = size_scaler.fit_transform(size).reshape(-1)
norm_price = price_scaler.fit_transform(price).reshape(-1)
norm_bedrooms = bedroom_scaler.fit_transform(bedrooms).reshape(-1)

graphWidth = 400
graphHeight = 300

f = plt.figure(figsize = (graphWidth / 100.0, graphHeight / 100.0), dpi = 100)

axes = Axes3D(f)
axes.scatter(norm_size, norm_bedrooms, norm_price, cmap="RdYlGn", edgecolors="black")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that is the idea! The values are a bit different but what matters is that the scale on the Y axis has gone.

Comment: Is this what you want ?

Comment: Well your axes seem to be flipped in the image you posted but in terms of the labelling (axes) yes.

Comment: I basically rotate your image with `axes.view_init(elev=20., azim=35)`.

Comment: Okay, would you mind posting your solution, or if it is the same code as mine, but with this rotation added then the issue is not resolved.

Comment: No I just turn off axis. updated my answer, Is it right ?

Comment: Yes precisely, only with the grid back on, however that is trivial.

Comment: Perfect! The issue was with "#matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)" causing this scale to appear, thank you! I would Upvote but my rep is too low sadly.

Comment: No worries. I am happy that helps.